# Finding the inverse of a complicated function

Tags: integration, ordinary-differential-equations, functions

I need to find $\rho=B^{-1}(t)$, where $$B(t) = \int_{0}^{t}\frac{1}{k-\frac{Bs+m_0}{As+w_0}}ds = \frac{A}{(kA-B)^2}\{(kA-B)t+[m_0-kw_0+(kA-B)\frac{w_0}{A}]ln\big|\frac{(kA-B)t}{kw_0-m_0}+1\big|\}.$$

This problem arises from use of the following: [Interpreting a proposition](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/669637/interpreting-a-proposition)
as well as in an attempt to solve the following problem: [What is this problem asking for?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/678617/what-is-this-problem-asking-for)

I don't know how to handle a $t$ term and a $\ln(t)$ term combined, in finding the inverse!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I properly understand your question, you want to extract $t$ from the rhs from
$B(t)=RHS(t)$.

What you can notice is that after some rearrangement the rhs write as
$$a+b t+c \log (d t+e)$$ So the equation you need to solve is $$B(t)=a+b t+c \log (d t+e)$$ The solution of this equation involves Lambert function and the result is
$$\frac{c d W\left(\frac{b e^{-\frac{a}{c}+\frac{b e}{c d}+\frac{B(t)}{c}}}{c
   d}\right)-b e}{b d}$$ Replacing $a,b,c,d,e$ by their corresponding definition should make things nicer (I hope).